# React Native how to implement custom oauth with own IDP server

Tags: oauth, react-native

I am trying to implement custom IDP login flow with own IDP server using React native

how to implement this ? is there any specific library available or any example ?

More details 
1. My assumption is it should behave live "login with facebook"
2. When user clicks a button -> iframe should take to myidp.login.com/login -> and gives one time token to me.